# CSS Specificty Issue - Grid inside Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, css-specificity

Is there a way to adapt the Specificity of classes to allow the use of a grid system as seen in this example?

```css
.col3 .width1 {
    background:blue;
}
.col4 .width1 {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col4">
    <div class="width1">
        <div class="col3">
            <div class="width1">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

[Seen in this FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/juz3boz8/)

The inner most  is red, not blue.

The issue comes from putting a grid inside a grid using the same class calls.

I understand that writing the CSS with the order I want the grids to take precedent will help, but I can not guarantee that the col3 and col4 will not change positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went a different route and through Sass just dynamically created all the classes I need in a style of:

grid(size)-block(size)

So it defines how large the grid is, then with the block, how much this div should take up of that grid size.

Size being defined by #x# [ x by y, row by column]

So would have the example of: .grid1x4-block1x2

The grid is then setup as 1 row with 4 possible spots, and this div takes up a block of 1 row by 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are looking for, but the reason the inside is not blue is because the style is being over-written by the `.col4 .width1` style. You can make the blue appear by simply applying an `!important` to the background of `.col3 .width`.

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdsechrest/7qdta38e/)

```css
 .col3 .width1 {
   background: blue !important;
   width: 70%;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .col4 .width1 {
   background: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col4">
  <div class="width1">
    <div class="col3">
      <div class="width1">
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this is not what you are looking for, could you please try to explain in more detail and I will try to do what I can to help you.

Comment: The problem, that this will be a much larger grid system. I do not want to place !important on every single class. I would end up using !important close to 50 times. As described earlier I cannot guarantee that the positioning will not switch, this means the !important tags will override each other in the same manner it is currently. To make this work in that fashion I would have to place of the !important tags on every single class putting me in exactly the same position.

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to achieve with this so I can better understand why you need to nest grids inside of grids inside of grids.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used separate classes for each attribute?

```
<div class="col4">
    <div class="width1">
        <div class="col3 color_blue">
            <div class="width1">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

.color_blue being what sets the div col13 to blue.

Like this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3e984vkn/)